# One activity two Intent filter

Tags: android

when I start activity first time
`getIntent().getAction()` shows action name `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` in `onResume()` method, after that i moved from this activity to another activity, from there I set the intent action `"com.example.CONTINUE_SERVICE"` & start previous activity. But still `getIntent().getAction()` shows action name `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` in `onResume()` method. I can't understand why getIntent().getAction() not shows action name `"com.example.CONTINUE_SERVICE"` in `onResume()` method.

Comment: show an example of your code plz

Answer (score 0):

`getIntent()` returns the `Intent` used to *create* the activity instance. Your symptoms would be explained if you are not creating a new activity instance, but instead are reusing an existing instance. This might occur due to `Intent` flags (e.g., `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`) or manifest settings (e.g., certain `android:launchMode` values). In these cases, the new `Intent` is delivered to `onNewIntent()` when the activity is brought back to the foreground.